# crontab -e No such file or directory

Tags: cron

I have a fresh instance of Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
I have not used or messed with the crontab previously.
When I run `crontab -e` I get `crontabs: No such file or directory`.
When I try to re-install crontab with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cron` I get:

```
Preparing to unpack .../cron_3.0pl1-136ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cron (3.0pl1-136ubuntu1) over (3.0pl1-136ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cron_3.0pl1-136ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/etc/cron.d/.placeholder.dpkg-new' (while processing './etc/cron.d/.placeholder'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cron_3.0pl1-136ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It's very confusing why the error message contains the word crontabs, and not crontab. Here a screenshot as proof I did not type crontabs -e.
[image]

Comment: Yes I did. I typed crontab (singular) but the error message contains the word crontabs (plural). Added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: hmm odd Is that an admin user? Oooh did you perhaps overwrite /usr/bin/crontab?

Comment: Good question - it's a regular user (not root). When i change to root this happens:

`emil@willdhorses4:~/github/wildhorses$ sudo -s

[sudo] password for emil: 
root@willdhorses4:/home/emil/github/wildhorses# crontab -e
crontabs: No such file or directory
crontabs: mkdir: Operation not permitted
root@willdhorses4:/home/emil/github/wildhorses#`

Comment: I didn't overwrite the `/usr/bin/crontab` but this is all so weird I am starting to wonder if digitalocean could be a factor in this, as this is where I host this VM.

Comment: Stumped so maybe someone else knows :D But do you need crontab? there is also `/etc/crontab` Only diff: you also include a user on the cron line

Comment: That works for me! And stops the bleeding, thanks :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't write in comments, I have to write here. It looks like I have [a similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723389/unable-to-create-file-in-cron-d-operation-not-permitted). Can't update/remove packages due to permission issues. Tell me, how did you decide? Or did you have to reinstall the system? Any help. Thanks.

Comment: I had to destroy and recreate the digital ocean droplet 7 times before I realized how the virus gets in. In the end it always entered my machine thru port mapping in the socat docker container. Check the documentation here: https://github.com/alpine-docker/socat
Adding "localhost" to the mapping solved the problem permanently. My error was trusting a tutorial that didn't include it. @Fill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a cryptominer argon2, which hacked my VM, locked me out of root and cron.