# cmake consumes 100% of CPU

Tags: cpu, cpu-load, resource-limiting

I noticed a very high CPU usage on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-125-generic x86_64).

Using `htop` I can see 3 processes with the command:

`/usr/share/[cmake] --config=/usr/share/[cmake].pid`

which take a huge share of CPUs (see screenshow below). I never heard of, or used cmake. How can I fix this? Thanks.
[image: htop screenshot]

Content of `cat /usr/share/[cmake].pid`:

```
{
"api": {
    "id": null,
    "worker-id": null
},
"http": {
    "enabled": false,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 0,
    "access-token": null,
    "restricted": true
},
"autosave": true,
"background": true,
"colors": true,
"title": true,
"randomx": {
    "init": -1,
    "init-avx2": -1,
    "mode": "auto",
    "1gb-pages": false,
    "rdmsr": true,
    "wrmsr": true,
    "cache_qos": false,
    "numa": true,
    "scratchpad_prefetch_mode": 1
},
"cpu": {
    "enabled": true,
    "huge-pages": true,
    "huge-pages-jit": false,
    "hw-aes": null,
    "priority": null,
    "memory-pool": false,
    "yield": true,
    "asm": true,
    "argon2-impl": null,
    "argon2": [0, 1],
    "cn": [
        [1, 0],
        [1, 1]
    ],
    "cn-heavy": [
        [1, 0],
        [1, 1]
    ],
    "cn-lite": [
        [1, 0],
        [1, 1]
    ],
    "cn-pico": [
        [2, 0],
        [2, 1]
    ],
    "cn/upx2": [
        [2, 0],
        [2, 1]
    ],
    "ghostrider": [
        [8, 0],
        [8, 1]
    ],
    "rx": [0, 1],
    "rx/wow": [0, 1],
    "cn-lite/0": false,
    "cn/0": false,
    "rx/arq": "rx/wow",
    "rx/keva": "rx/wow"
},
"opencl": {
    "enabled": false,
    "cache": true,
    "loader": null,
    "platform": "AMD",
    "adl": true
},
"cuda": {
    "enabled": false,
    "loader": null,
    "nvml": true
},
"log-file": "/tmp/ddns.log",
"donate-level": 1,
"donate-over-proxy": 1,
"pools": [
    {
        "algo": null,
        "coin": null,
        "url": "194.36.190.30:1414",
        "user": null,
        "pass": null,
        "rig-id": null,
        "nicehash": false,
        "keepalive": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "tls": false,
        "tls-fingerprint": null,
        "daemon": false,
        "socks5": null,
        "self-select": null,
        "submit-to-origin": false
    },
    {
        "algo": null,
        "coin": null,
        "url": "194.36.190.30:1414",
        "user": null,
        "pass": null,
        "rig-id": null,
        "nicehash": false,
        "keepalive": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "tls": false,
        "tls-fingerprint": null,
        "daemon": false,
        "socks5": null,
        "self-select": null,
        "submit-to-origin": false
    },
    {
        "algo": null,
        "coin": null,
        "url": "194.36.190.30:1414",
        "user": null,
        "pass": null,
        "rig-id": null,
        "nicehash": false,
        "keepalive": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "tls": false,
        "tls-fingerprint": null,
        "daemon": false,
        "socks5": null,
        "self-select": null,
        "submit-to-origin": false
    }
],
"retries": 5,
"retry-pause": 5,
"print-time": 60,
"health-print-time": 60,
"dmi": true,
"syslog": false,
"tls": {
    "enabled": false,
    "protocols": null,
    "cert": null,
    "cert_key": null,
    "ciphers": null,
    "ciphersuites": null,
    "dhparam": null
},
"dns": {
    "ipv6": false,
    "ttl": 30
},
"user-agent": null,
"verbose": 0,
"watch": true,
"pause-on-battery": false,
"pause-on-active": false
```

}

Comment: The file `/usr/share/[cmake]` looks suspicious. If you don't know what this is, it's probably a cryptominer that got installed. Did you run any scripts without checking the contents first? Please let us know the contents of the config file and include `cat /usr/share/[cmake].pid` in your question.

Comment: See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150346/crypto-miner-malware) for possible locations to check for auto-startup files, which probably start the process at boot.

Comment: I don't recall installing any unknown scripts, I basically only have Docker and Docker Compose installed there, and run AirFlow and Postgres in them. What is very interesting, is that I also have this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426133/crontab-e-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Well, there is a cryptominer called [argon2](https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-argon2), which is also referenced in the config, so there could be a connection there. Also notice the entries called "algo" and "coin". You could also have a look at the logfile: `/tmp/ddns.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a cryptominer pretending it's CMake.

Delete it immediately, look for similarly named files (or monitor outgoing connections and note the suspicious ones), and most importantly check your machine for network security.